# Emails from Google Apps to custom SMTP server delayed by 1 hour consistently

Tags: smtp, g-suite, gmail, email

The outgoing mails from Google Apps/Gmail to our own custom SMTP server are getting delayed by 1 hour consistently.  mxtoolbox.com diagnostics of our custom SMTP server are looking OK. Our custom SMTP server is receiving emails from other sources (yahoo, hotmail etc.) on time.

Looking at the SMTP logs show a delay in a google intermediate SMTP server.

```
Received: by qwi2 with SMTP id 2so1989393qwi.3 for <y@sub.mydomain.com>; Thu, 27 Jan 2011 03:54:23 -0800 (PST) MIME-Version: 1.0 
Received: by 10.224.19.203 with SMTP id c11mr1587082qab.170.1296125657457;  Thu, 27 Jan 2011 02:54:17 -0800 (PST)
```

This setup has been working fine for a year though our custom email server was missing a reverse DNS entry and SPF records.  Thinking that this could be the cause of the issue, we added these entries a week ago. But the issue still persists.

Here are are more details:
We are using Google Apps to host our primary domain email (say: mydomain.com)
The custom SMTP server (say: s1.mydomain.com) hosts our subdomain (say: sub.mydomain.com)

This is how the email log looks from x@mydomain.com to y@sub.mydomain.com

```
Return-Path: x@mydomain.com
Received: from localhost.localdomain (LHLO s1.mydomain.com) (127.0.0.1) by
s1.mydomain.com with LMTP; Thu, 27 Jan 2011 17:24:28 +0530 (IST)
Received: from localhost (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
by s1.mydomain.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 605116A6565
for <y@sub.mydomain.com>; Thu, 27 Jan 2011 17:24:28 +0530 (IST)
X-Virus-Scanned: amavisd-new at sub.mydomain.com
X-Spam-Flag: NO
X-Spam-Score: 2.984
X-Spam-Level: **
X-Spam-Status: No, score=2.984 tagged_above=-10 required=6.6
t    ests=[AWL=-0.337, BAYES_50=0.001, DNS_FROM_OPENWHOIS=1.13,
FH_DATE_PAST_20XX=3.188, HTML_MESSAGE=0.001,
HTML_OBFUSCATE_05_10=0.001, RCVD_IN_DNSWL_LOW=-1] autolearn=no
Received: from s1.mydomain.com ([127.0.0.1])
by localhost (s1.mydomain.com [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024)
with ESMTP id RBjF7Wwr44mP for <y@sub.mydomain.com>;
Thu, 27 Jan 2011 17:24:24 +0530 (IST)
Received: from mail-qw0-f44.google.com (mail-qw0-f44.google.com [209.85.216.44])
by s1.mydomain.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id BB5DE6A6512
for <y@sub.mydomain.com>; Thu, 27 Jan 2011 17:24:23 +0530 (IST)
Received: by qwi2 with SMTP id 2so1989393qwi.3
        for <y@sub.mydomain.com>; Thu, 27 Jan 2011 03:54:23 -0800 (PST)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.224.19.203 with SMTP id c11mr1587082qab.170.1296125657457;
Thu, 27 Jan 2011 02:54:17 -0800 (PST)
Received: by 10.220.117.17 with HTTP; Thu, 27 Jan 2011 02:54:17 -0800 (PST)
Date: Thu, 27 Jan 2011 16:24:17 +0530
Message-ID: <AANLkTinguyT8m44VSo8edkhzWd6y+jZE-2FwGr2Ss7Q3@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: test : 16:24
From: X <x@mydomain.com>
To: y@sub.mydomain.com
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=0015175cba2865a5fe049ad1c5cd
```

We appreciate any help that could help solve this issue :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like google's being greylisted.